# Initializing of objects with data from text files

Tags: c#, oop, object

I have 2 classes, one "Bicycle" and one "User". The first one has the following attributes:

```
private readonly int codeB;
private string name_parking_station;
int km_made;
```

and the second one:

```
private string name;
private int codeB;
private int utilization_duration;
```

Both classes have constructors with parameters and getters/setters. My question is: how do I instantiate objects from both classes with data from text files for which I've created? And also, how do I add them to 2 different ListView-s?

Comment: Fine, How the textfile Looks like? do you have any example?

Comment: 100 //codeB
Grozavesti // name_parking_station
20 // km_made

Comment: If you are able to read the Text file property then you may use REFLECTION to inject all the properties into class variables. Check this link for the guidance on [reflection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the text file format? If so, you can use out of the box serialization. [You could also build your own custom serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx). That said, you may need to rethink your `readonly` property as this will not serialize.

[From MSDN for standard XML Serialization:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
MySerializableClass myObject;
// Construct an instance of the XmlSerializer with the type
// of object that is being deserialized.
XmlSerializer mySerializer = 
new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
// To read the file, create a FileStream.
FileStream myFileStream = 
new FileStream("myFileName.xml", FileMode.Open);
// Call the Deserialize method and cast to the object type.
myObject = (MySerializableClass) mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

Comment: "That said, you may need to rethink your readonly property as this will not serialize." - Or write a serializer than can use ctor's

Comment: The json.net serializer is the most downloaded nuget package of all time, and it can handle xml aswell. I can recomment looking it up. @MurrayFoxcroft

Comment: Json.net is awesome. I stuck with an answer that did not require 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 0):

If your Bicycle lines don't contain those '//' parts, just your data, it's easy to create Bicycle objects by reading the file line by line and process the lines like this:

```
// let your class have an appropriate creator
internal Bicycle(int codeB, string name_parking_station, int km_made)
{
    this.codeB = codeB;
    this.name_parking_station = name_parking_station;
    this.km_made = km_made;
}

// In your line reader loop:
// lineRead contains the current line
var lineParts = lineRead.Split(' ').Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item)).ToArray();        

// lineParts now should contain 3 strings

if(lineParts.Length == 3)
{
    var bicycle = new Bicycle(int.Parse(lineParts[0]), lineParts[1], int.Parse(lineParts[2]));
    // add your new object to a collection of Bicycle objects
}
```

Data validation is left out to keep things simple. I suggest you use int.TryParse().
Let me know if my assumption about the line format is not correct.
How exactly would you like to present your Bicycle objects in a ListView?